# How can i get the solr documents with only one value in multi valued field?

Tags: solr, solrj, facet

I need to get the documents from solr index, where the documents has only one value in multivauled field.

Say,following data in index.

```
            <doc>
            <label>
            <id ="1">1</id>
            <id ="2">2</id>
            <label>
            </doc>
            <doc>
            <label>
            <id ="3">3</id>
            <label>
            </doc>

            <doc>
            <label>
            <id ="4">4</id>
            <id ="5">5</id>
            <label>
            </doc>
            <doc>
            <label>
            <id ="6">6</id>
            <label>
            </doc>
```

I need the following result,

```
            <doc>
            <label>
            <id ="3">3</id>
            <label>
            </doc>

            <doc>
            <label>
            <id ="6">6</id>
            <label>
            </doc>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add Stateless Script Update Processor in your updateRequestProcessorChain which adds a new field to the document when that document has 1 value in the multi-valued field.
Or you can use  CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory < http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_0_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory.html > for counting
search on basis of that field.